# Authenticate a PHP application using Azure Active Directory connection

Tags: php, azure, active-directory

I work as an intern in my college and we want to build an app. Of course, our university has an active directory and we use Azure and Azure also has our AD. I am building the front-end and need to implement login using Azure AD SSO. How could I do that? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what have you attempted ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, AAD is an SSO redirect only, so you register your your callback endpoint, direct users from your app to Azure, they sign on, and get redirected to your callback

Comment: @KenLee I actually haven't made the actual front-end. I am trying to test if Azure AD SSO can work. If it does then only we will proceed. If not, we will use CAS SSO that our university already has. All I have is a dummy PHP app and a dummy Next.js app. I am trying to see if I can implement simple login using either of those app and then we will go from there. Thank you

Comment: @ChrisHaas I think that is the way to go. But do you have any ideas on how I do that? Any resources that you know? Or any sample code? Or anything? All I need is to authenticate a user based on our AD which we have in Azure too. Thanks.

Comment: I'd start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/plan-an-application-integration). They are saying "applications" but that includes web applications

Answer (score 1):

•   You can refer the below code to add the identity provider’s authentication connection settings in the php application configuration files. The following code will help you to add a section to your existing php web app code in authentication sources file to configure and provision SSO through azure AD.

[image: AAD SSO URL]

•   Once the above code has been placed and configured in the PHP application, now add the PHP application in app registrations in Azure AD and provide the web redirect URI for your PHP application and provide the SSO configuration details in the SSO pane like federation metadata URL, SAML or WS-Fed Sign in or sign out URLs. Once done, check the below code for confirmation of SAML endpoint URL for the Azure AD configured in the PHP authentication config file.

[image: PHP SAML SSO]

[image: PHP app SAML Metadata file]

•   The below snapshot shows the how the SAML token authentication is redirected to Azure AD and its configuration in PHP app. Also, how its attributes and claims are passed from the Azure AD to the PHP app for service granting and authentication purposes.

[image: Redirect attributes]

Thus, in this way, you can configure a PHP application to authenticate with Azure AD through SSO. Please find the below links for more information: -

https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Open/Using-SimpleSAML-to-authenticate-PHP-applications-with-Azure-AD

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-vs-authorization#web-application-to-web-api